# can I release my app when previous app is in review(same app with different version)

Tags: google-play-console

can I release my app when previous app is in review(same app with different version)

I just release version 6 app and I forget to add real ads and so I added ads and version is now 7. Can i release that version 7 app right now.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Just create a new release, add version 7 and publish it. This will override version 6 and replace it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, but keep in mind that the APK of the previous version (6) will be disabled by the new version, as soon as the new one is approved.[image: two versions in review]